# numerical methods for the system of differential equations

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I need to solve this system of differential equations by ballistic method.
$$\begin{cases}\dot{w}=-2ew+u; 
   \\\dot{u}=4eu-4(e^2-w^2)w;\end{cases}$$
where $e<0; w(0)=w_{0}(\text{any number}); u(0)=?; $
I have written a program, but I think it doesn't work correct.
Here is my code from Matlab:

```
clear all
e=-1; 
eps = 0:2:10;
N=100;
f=@(z,e)[-2*e*z(1)+z(2); 4*e*z(2)-4*(e^2-z(1)^2)*z(1)];
h=(5)/(N-1);
for l=1:length(eps)
    iter = 0;
    v0=1.4; v1=0.7;
    while (abs(v1-v0))>(e)&(iter<20) 
        v0=v1;
        y(1,1)=0.6; y(2,1)=v0;
        for n=1:(N-1)
            k1=f(y(:,n),eps(l));
            k2=f(y(:,n)+0.5*h*k1,eps(l));
            k3=f(y(:,n)+0.5*h*k2,eps(l));
            k4=f(y(:,n)+0.5*h*k3,eps(l));
            y(:,n+1)=y(:,n)+(h/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);
        end
        v1=v0-(y(1,N)-1)/y(2,N);
        iter=iter+1;
    end
    hold on
    plot(0:h:5,y(1,:));
end
```

Thank you for the help!
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Also, not everyone is in the same time zone. It's  the evening here in England.

Comment: What exactly is the "ballistic method"? Do you mean a shooting method to solve a boundary value problem? What is the second boundary condition? How do you detect "it doesn't work correct"? Do you have a reference solution, some expected qualitative behavior,...?

Comment: What parts of your code are you certain about, where did you throw things at the wall to see what sticks? Check again the coefficient structure of Kutta's 4th order method.